# max in python - error missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Tags: python, arguments, max, typeerror

I am trying to do one exercise on python (my version is python33
The exercise reads:

> Write a function find_longest_word1() that takes a list of words and returns the length of the longest one. Use only higher order functions.

My attempt is:

```
def find_longest_word1(a):
    out = max(list(map(len,a)))
    print (out)
find_longest_word1(["This","is","a","listing"])
```

The error which I get is:

```
max() missing 1 required positional argument 'b'
```

I have passed one list as argument. Do I need to give some other argument to max function ?

Comment: Have you done `from numpy import *` somewhere in your code? Or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. My code from previous exercise had user-defined max function with two arguments. Bad on my part.

Comment: this works fine in my pc

Answer (score 6):

The `max()` function you are calling isn't the [standard built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max), but is some other function called `max()`: the built-in doesn't have an argument called `b` so the error message cannot possibly be about it.

Please double-check whether you've defined (or imported) a function called `max()`. If I were to guess, I'd expect the definition to look like this:

```
def max(a, b):
   ...
```

Your code works fine here (with the built-in `max()`):

```
In [50]: a = ["This", "is", "a", "listing"]

In [51]: max(list(map(len, a)))
Out[51]: 7
```

By the way, the call to `list()` is unnecessary:

```
In [52]: max(map(len, a))
Out[52]: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use key:

```
>>> my_list = ["This","is","a","listing"]
>>> max(my_list, key=len)
'listing'
```

you question say to return length:

```
>>> len(max(my_list, key=len))
7
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs problem, he's wondering why the `max` function is asking for a `b` argument. You've just given him a solution using the builtin `max` but if he's overwritten the `max` function (which seems reasonable to assume) then your solution still won't work.